# Is there a canon source from the 1980s covering the death of Matt Tracker's brother from the MASK franchise

Tags: comics, cartoon, idw-comics, mobile-armored-strike-kommand

Many modern fan sites covering the Mobile Armored Strike Kommand (MASK) franchise say that Matt Tracker and Miles Mayhem were originally  partners, but that they split up to form MASK and Venom respectively after Mayhem killed Tracker's brother.

Is there a canonical source from either the 1980s toyline, animated series, or comic that covers this (and if so, where may I find it)? Or was this introduced later the later IDW comic series or is fanon?

Comment: Given that I owned a couple of MASK toys as a kid in the 80s, I'm amazed that anyone is still talking about it - let alone 4 questions in one day on this site!

Comment: IDW rebooted it as a comic.

Answer (score 12):

Yes. This is sourced in Kenner’s promo mini-comic #1, [Flaming Beginnings](https://www.battlegrip.com/m-a-s-k-mini-comic-flaming-beginnings/), published by DC Comics and released in 1985 with first generation of toys. These comics were packaged with the first vehicles released.

[image]

As a promotional advertisement branded by Kenner, the implication is the story was intended to apply to the toys, which predated the cartoon and cartoon story which was developed from the toys.

Comment: Well, that was simple. I don't think that these comics were released in my market.